# Increasing user defined camera screen resolution in Android

Tags: android, screen, android-camera, resolution

How to increase user defined camera screen Resolution in android. In my business card reader android application, I want to increase the camera resolution for better quality of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know exactly but I think this can help you. All below steps must be done before starting camera. **If you want to set resolution for video then you need to set preview size otherwise for picture you need to set picture size in your camera using camera paramters.** Closest resolution will be set if given resolution not supported.

First get your camera.

```
Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
```

Get camera parameters and set preview size in camera parameters.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
```

Then you can set parameters to camera.
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

You can use all above properties for picture are also instead of preview.

Get camera parameters and set preview size in camera parameters.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPictureSize(width, height);
```

Then you can set parameters to camera.

```
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

you can also get supported format sizes using

```
getSupportedPictureSizes() 
or
getSupportedPreviewSizes()
```

if you need any help or any tutorial for camera then you can ask. If possible I will try to help you.

Comment: if im using parameters.setPictureSize(width, height) it will give exception like "java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed",and how to define width and height, in my program i use for getting highest width and height for   WindowManager window1 = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(
    Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
  DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  window1.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);
  width = outMetrics.widthPixels;
  height = outMetrics.heightPixels;

Comment: not getting what exactly you are asking can you be more specific.

Comment: actually my problem is increasing the camera resolution for better quality of image, in my business card reader,i use tess-two OCR library for getting text from cropped image. in that i get only 20-40% accurate result. so here i want to increase the maximum size of camera resolution to 1.5/or more times bigger/large resolution.(here i get max size of camera resolution by using parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();). sorry for bad English, n thanks.

Comment: Ok you tell me how you are capturing picture from camera. You have used onPictureTaken for you purpose.

Comment: yes, i want to capturing image from camera , 1.5/more bigger/larger than maximum resolution of camera.